# How can I run 2 commands within 1 button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm developing a game that wants to check wether a certain puzzle is solved or not. This puzzle is inside a UserControl, and if it is solved I want to show another UserControl.

The method to change one UserControl1 to UserControl2 is inside the MainWindowViewModel, and I have been able to solve this issue with this command:

```
Button 1:
<Button Content="Grid" Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="5" />
```

The logic thing would be to pass the Puzzle as a variable and let the second UserControl check if the Puzzle is solved, but given how this command is coded within the MainViewModel that isn't possible. The *MainViewModel* looks like this:

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private IPage content;
        public IPage Content { get => content; protected set => Set(ref content, value); }
        public RelayCommand<int> NavigateCommand => new RelayCommand<int>(Navigate);

        private readonly Dictionary<int, Lazy<IPage>> pages = new Dictionary<int, Lazy<IPage>>
        {
            [1] = new Lazy<IPage>(() => new IntroViewModel()),
            [2] = new Lazy<IPage>(() => new ChoosePuzzleViewModel()),
            [3] = new Lazy<IPage>(() => new GameViewModel(5)),
            [4] = new Lazy<IPage>(() => new GameViewModel(7)),
            [5] = new Lazy<IPage>(() => new GameViewModel(9)),
            [6] = new Lazy<IPage>(() => new ResultViewModel())
        };

        public MainViewModel() => Navigate(1);

        public void Navigate(int value) => Content = pages[value].Value;
    }
```

So the solution I am trying to apply is to let the PuzzleViewModel check wether the puzzle is correct with a Button, just like this:

```
Button 2:
<Button Name="SolveButton" Content="Check" Height="80" Width="100" Command="{Binding VMPuzzle.SolvedCheck}" />
```

And depending on the result this Command returns, run the *Button 1* command.
It is not necessary that the second Command is in a Button, that is for illustration purposes.

So the question is, would it be possible for one Button to run two commands, one after the other?

Comment: "depending on the result this Command returns" - ICommand implementation doesn't return any results (`void Execute(object)`). however view models can communicate with each other - either via direct rerefence, or indirectly, e.g. with EventAggregator

Comment: Didn't notice the Execute method is void. Could you elaborate on how the ViewModels can communicate with each other via direct reference? Would that make it possible to call the RelayCommand method inside the MainViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could execute the "NavigateCommand" from the VMPuzzle ViewModel if you have a reference to your MainViewModel class. You can fire the command with

NavigateCommand.Execute();

The implementation of the VMPuzzle class would be useful to see.

Example:

```
public class VMPuzzle
{
    MainViewModel _mainViewModel;

    public VMPuzzle(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        _mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
    }

    private void CallExecuteCommandInMainViewModel()
    {
        _mainViewModel.NavigateCommand.Execute();
    }
}
```

CallExecuteCommandInMainViewModel(); 
would be called from the SolvedCheck Command in your VMPuzzle Class or you directly fire it with 
_mainViewModel.NavigateCommand.Execute(); 
without a method.

I assume you have direct access to your MainViewModel so you can directly call NavigateCommand.Execute(); in your SolvedCheckCommand. 
Because of the Binding i see in your example: 
Command="{Binding VMPuzzle.SolvedCheck}"

Alternatively you could work with a EventHandler like in this example "i didnt implement the Commands itself in this example but the execute void:

EDIT: added summaries for clarification purposes only

```
using System;

namespace Testproject
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // Subscribe to the event in VMPuzzle but dont forget to unsuscribe later if needed!
            var vm_Puzzle = new VMPuzzle();
            vm_Puzzle.SolvedCheck += Vm_Puzzle_SolvedCheck;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="VMPuzzle.Execute_CommandSolvedCheck(object)"/> 
        /// got executed so we want to do something after that.
        /// In this example we execute another command
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Vm_Puzzle_SolvedCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Fire the Navigate Command
            // NavigateCommand.Execute();
        }
    }

    public class VMPuzzle
    {
        public VMPuzzle()
        {
            doStuff();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Method which gets executed from the Command
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Parameter"></param>
        private void Execute_CommandSolvedCheck(object Parameter)
        {
            OnSolvedCheck(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute_CommandSolvedCheck is completely executed, inform subscribers if there are some
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnSolvedCheck(EventArgs e)
        {
            SolvedCheck?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Just a standard Method we fire
        /// </summary>
        public void doStuff()
        {
            OnSolvedCheck(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public event EventHandler SolvedCheck;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried the first option, but the VMPuzzle is initialized inside the GameViewModel, which is in turn created inside that the *pages* Dictionary. I tried giving the instance of MainViewModel in there, but `this` won't work inside the initialization of the Dictionary. Is there a workaround to that aswell? If there's not I'll go with the EventHandler option, the first one seems simpler at first glance though.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can provide several parameters for a class (ViewModel) in this example "GameViewModel" to have a reference to your MainViewModel. Means you can give your GameViewModel the reference to your MainViewModel Class via parameter and use it there and store it in a field like provided in the first answer.

For the second approach I know it looks very hard at first glance for a newcomer but if you read about it, you soon get the grasp of it and it will feel easy. I would suggest you some videos from Tim Corey about that. If you have further questions let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although I used the first approach, I ended up understanding the second approach thanks to the Tim Corey videos.

Comment: Glad it helped. Now I understand what the problem was in your first approach. The dictionary can be initialized in the constructor of the class or in another method if you want or need to use "this" and it would be possible to assign the values there too. Interfaces can't have a constructor to ship parameters to it so you could've used an abstract class or a standard class for this.